# opencl image write (typed write) to local memory

Tags: image, 3d, 2d, opencl, local

Im trying to write an image to local  memory. Is it possible to use typed access to shared local memory or should I 'manually' write each channel?
I have not come across any examples where local memory is used to manipulate images. Considering that ocl doe snot allow an image buffer to be both read and write, Im wondering if this even possible.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, the image types can only be used for data in global memory. If you wish to store intermediate results in local memory, you will need to use the regular data types (`uint`, `float`, `uint4`, `float4` etc).